# Is there a way to prevent content from being selected for copying or being printable for Drupal sites?

Tags: 7, users

I would like the to display some content to users that would be viewable, but not easily duplicated by users without permission.  Do major browsers provide a setting option, or is there a way that Drupal can mange this action?

Answer (score 4):

I am unaware of any way to do this out of the box, and the problem isn't really related to Drupal.  The problem is just a user selecting text in the browser and doing a Crtl-C.

While not foolproof, you can use CSS and/or jQuery shenanigans to place a `<div>` over your content with a transparent background PNG.  This should make the text beneath it unselectable.  It will also make any links unclickable.  You could add some permission logic to only do this for certain user roles.

This does not prevent anyone doing a view-source, wget, or any other method for getting at the markup.  If it's on the web, someone will figure out a method for getting it.

Comment: +1 for the tip re: transparent background.  I know there is no foolproof options, but I'm not trying to block the content from web developers or Drupalists :)

Comment: Giving this an upvote because it won't tax your server a ton (converting text to images is wasteful), and will allow you to still remain flexible w/r/t design. As long as you understand there really is no way to prevent copying data from *everyone*. There's *always* a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

As MPD already mentioned, it is not really a Drupal problem but rather more general.
Something that might help in your case is [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/), a method to replace text with images. It's somewhat obsolete now with @font-face being widely supported, but it could be a solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like phpThumb to create an image from your text.

Check out this demo:
http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/demo/phpThumb.demo.demo.php#x51

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve that by [Copy Prevention](https://drupal.org/project/copyprevention) module.

From module page:

> This module includes several different technical ways/methods to make copying/stealing information/images from your site harder than it usually is:
>
> - Disable text selection
> - Disable copy to clipboard
> - Disable right-click context menu on all site content
> - Disable right-click context menu only on images ( tag)
> - Place transparent image above all your images - this will protect
>   your real images from being saved using context menu or drag-and-drop
>   to desktop
> - Protect/hide your images from search engine indexes so that your
>   images don't show up in image searches - add "noimageindex" robots
>   tag and disallow image files indexing in robots.txt

I've tested all the features of this module and works great!